# Android - 文字入力の確定検知について

Tags: android

こんばんは。

EditTextの入力終了検知を確定を検出することで行おうと考えています。検索で次のようなコードを見つけました。

```
edit1.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher()
{
        int currentLength = 0;

    @Override
    public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {}

    @Override
    public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {
        currentLength = s.toString().length();
    }

    @Override
    public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
        Log.v("", "after:" + s.toString());
        if (s.toString().length() < currentLength) {
            return;
        }
        boolean unfixed = false;
        Object[] spanned = s.getSpans(0, s.length(), Object.class);
        if (spanned != null) {
            for (Object obj : spanned) {
                if (obj instanceof android.text.style.UnderlineSpan) {
                    unfixed = true;
                }
            }
        }
        if (!unfixed) {
            Toast toast = Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "確定", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
            toast.show();
        }
    }
});
```

うまく動作するのですが、確定後にソフトキーボードのDeleteキーを押したときにも、確定が発生します。

これを防ぐ方法はありますでしょうか？

よろしくお願いいたします。

Comment: このコードは[こちら](http://www.spiritek.co.jp/spkblog/2012/10/25/androidedittext%E3%81%A7ime%E3%81%AE%E6%9C%AA%E7%A2%BA%E5%AE%9A%E6%96%87%E5%AD%97%E5%88%97%E3%81%8C%E7%A2%BA%E5%AE%9A%E3%81%95%E3%82%8C%E3%81%9F%E7%9E%AC%E9%96%93/)に詳しい説明が載っています。

Comment: また、確定検知を変更した例として[次の投稿](http://qiita.com/amay077/items/73da05ab80d23e28703a)があります。

Answer (score 3, accepted):

調べた結果、ソフトキーボードのDeleteキーが入力されると、`onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count)`の[countが0になる](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12202047/detect-backspace-in-textwatcher)そうです。

そこで、次のようにしました。

```
edit1.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

    boolean keycodeFlag = false; // 上記コードに追加

    @Override
    public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {

        // このブロック追加
        if (count == 0) {
            keycodeFlag = true;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {

        if (s.toString().length() < currentLength || keycodeFlag) {   // 変更
            keycodeFlag = false;  // 追加
            return;
        }
    }
}
```

これで、質問内容のDeleteキーが確定として検知されるのを防ぐことができるようになりました。
（Genymotionエミュレータ上Android 4.2.2, 4.4.4, 5.0で確認）